# Mock Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() in test init method

Tags: java, testing, junit, static, mocking

I have the next block of code:

```
public void init() {
    facultyList = new ArrayList<>();
    localeFile = new Properties();
    try {
        localeFile.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(loadFileName()));
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        LOG.error("Host: " + ((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getRemoteHost()
                + " | Error in constructing of LocaleModel. More: " + e);
    }
}
```

Any possible solutions to mock `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` or how can I test this `catch` block?

Comment: You can set a custom context class loader:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setContextClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader)

Comment: What do you want to test exactly? The exception handling? Just ensure that the file isn't on the classpath.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you is right! Post the answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @BrettOkken sorry, I was wrong with recipient. Your answer helped me exactly. You can post it. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should refactor and isolate the expression in a separate method, and then mock its result
`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(loadFileName())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a custom context class loader. It is important to keep track of the original context class loader and put it back into context when your test is done.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setContextClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setContextClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29)